# How to receive and save an image in HTTP post request in Python Sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

I am new in sockets at python and I need to send an image using POST request from the client and save the image on the server.

I think I have prepared the client correctly, But I am not sure.

This is my client code:

```
import httplib

def printText(txt):
    lines = txt.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        print line.strip()

httpServ = httplib.HTTPConnection("127.0.0.1", 80)

httpServ.connect()



var = raw_input("Please enter a path of an image: ")

image = open(var, 'rb')
image_data = image.read()
image.close()

httpServ.request('POST', '/uplaod', image_data)


response = httpServ.getresponse()
if response.status == httplib.OK:
    print "Output from CGI request"
    printText(response.read())

httpServ.close()
```

My question is that how do I recieve that image on the server side and how do I save the image that i recieve in some path.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use the Bottle library when I want to create a quick-n-dirty web service.   Something like:

```
import bottle

app=bottle.app()

@app.post('/upload')
def doUpload():
    upload      = request.files['upload']
    upload.save('filename')

app.run()
```

Obviously this would have to be tweaked based on your hosting requirements.